# PHP how sha1 get this?

Tags: php, sha1, encryption, smf

I have my own little website and encrypting with sha1, now i try connect it to a SMF forum, but the sha1 codes is not the same?

My code

```
$password = "thisisatestpass";
$encrypted_password=sha1($password);
echo $encrypted_password; //03d858ce5f3b29b153b0392f196cff6f6e8684d0
```

SMF: 78481983d348ce4fbfabaccbb59af8ea95471f0c

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it, you don't need the SALT to do this, all you need is the username and the password.

The PHP code looks like this:

```
$username = "name";
$password = "pass";

$login = sha1($username.$password);
```

I asked for this and i just needed some time to try many ways, then this one worked.
Thx any way guys :)

Answer (score 1):

[According to this thread](http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=341776.0), SMF salts the password with the lowercased username before passing it through sha1.

Try `sha1(strtolower($your_username) . $password);`

Comment: Since version 2.0 SMF uses a salt which is stored in the database.

Comment: I was looking at it, but it gives me this: a81648ec3256deb019964d19be20bc2bd2d58c71

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find the salt used and then try to hash with

```
sha1($the_salt.$password);
```

You should try looking for the hash with phpMyAdmin in the tables used by SMF.
And according to what I see on smf support forums, using an alternate integration with hooks must be more robust (keeping in mind the changes done to hashing in the previous versions)

Comment: Yea, but how do i make the salt, when they make a user?

Comment: You'll have to find what salt they use (for eg, if it is "Asdfasvasdkjbsadf", $the_salt will be equal to "Asdfasvasdkjbsadf".

Answer (score 0):

As i know, SMF use salt for hashes. So, try to look for salt in database.

Comment: Try SHA1(username + password + salt)

Comment: Also, i found this: sha1(sha1(strtolower($username) . $password) . $salt).

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the source code of SMF 2.0.8 (Profile-Modify.php) you can see that the password is generated as follows:

```
// Go then.
$passwd = sha1(strtolower($cur_profile['member_name']) . un_htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwrd1']));
```

Please be aware that you need SMF [un_htmlspecialchars()](http://support.simplemachines.org/function_db/index.php?action=view_function;id=601) function in order to get 100% correct results.